# tar refuses to write archive contents to terminal

Tags: linux, tar, chrome

I'm trying to install linux on my computer and it was going smoothly until I put in this command

```
curl https://chrx.org/ | sudo tar xzfc - /usr/local && chrx
tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option
```

so I tried removing the x, then the c, and to both I got

```
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
```

This is my first time going this deep into a computer. I just wanna play minecraft lmao, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using a pipe, `command | tar ... -`. Download the file (`-o` option in `curl`) and then try to run the right `tar` command. Do check `man tar` for each of the options. And please remove the extraneous tags in the question and add full commands and outputs to the question, however simple the modification you make in each step you try.

Comment: would i use "curl -O https:// chrx.org/" to download it? I'm sorry, I've never even opened the terminal before yesterday lol

Comment: this is not how it works. You ask a question and the accept the answer provided to you, if it solved your issue. You don't post a new answer with the same content. What you just did is taking credit for someonelse's answer. So, you should remove your answer and accept the one that solved your issue. That's one of the rewards helpers receive.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that you are downloading and running unkown content with full rights (`sudo`). If you trust `chrx` and you are just learning to use the terminal, you really really want to stick to the instructions. The command you ran was:

```
curl https://chrx.org/ | sudo tar xzfc - /usr/local && chrx
```

And the one [on the page's](https://chrx.org/) *step-by-step* is:

```
curl https://chrx.org/ | sudo tar xzfC - /usr/local && chrx
```

The difference is the  `C` (uppercase in your command, lowercase in the original). In these cases, until you feel comfortable with the terminal and the command line, your best bet is to copy/paste.

Commands, options and filenames on Unix systems are case-sensitive and, on top of that, a typo may carry pretty awful consequences, even more so when running with full rights.

Comment: holy shit i cant believe i've been stressing for 24 hours over a lowercase "c", thank you so much!

Comment: Your proposal with the upper case C does not work with `tar` since `-C` is not amongst the classical `tar keyletters` from 1978. The fact that it works for you is caused by the fact that you are using the incorrect `gtar` implementation with a problematic CLI parser that is not `tar` compatible.

Comment: @schily, please not that I was not proposing the tar command, but pointing out what the original line at the site's step-by-step is! Your point, however valid, does not really concern the answer, it's not like I can change their document. Feels kind of unfair to be downvoted because or that.

Comment: I am not one of these downvoting trolls. I write comments that help people to understand problems in answers. This was a comment triggered by the fact that many people claim that `star` does not implement a `tar` compatible CLI, but `star` is just closer to `tar` than `gtar` is...and people should know where `gtar` deviates from `tar`.